# How to make Provider while I have Factory?

Tags: angularjs

Currently I'm working with Blur Admin template and I have a case which sidebar menu should appear depends on user role.

After gave it a try I discover that if I comment `$stateProvider.state(....);` for example in `app/pages/components/components.module.js` so `Components` menu will disappear from sidebar menu.

So from here I think I can implement defining state depends on user role maybe something like this

```
if(user_role == "partner"){
 $stateProvider.state(....);
}
```

So on in other pages module.

So far I have factory which check current user role which is get from `localStorage`

My problem is state definition located at `.config()` **which only accept Provider**.

So my question is How I can make provider to check current user role when I have factory to do it.

Here is `app/pages/components/components.module.js`

```
  angular.module('BlurAdmin.pages.components', [
    'BlurAdmin.pages.components.mail',
    'BlurAdmin.pages.components.timeline',
    'BlurAdmin.pages.components.tree',
  ])
      .config(routeConfig);
      // should .provider("CheckCurrentUserRole", CheckCurrentUserRole);

function CheckCurrentUserRole(){
 ///provider code here
}


  /** @ngInject */
  function routeConfig($stateProvider, /*CheckCurrentUserRoleProvider*/) {

    //if(CheckcurrentUserRole.method() == "partner"){

    $stateProvider
        .state('components', {
          url: '/components',
          template : '<ui-view></ui-view>',
          abstract: true,
          title: 'Components',
          sidebarMeta: {
            icon: 'ion-gear-a',
            order: 200,
          },
        });

     //} so if current user is not partner then components sidebar menu doesn't appear.

  }
```

Here is my factory to check user role

```
angular.module('BlurAdmin.pages')
.factory('authFactory', function (sessionFactory, $http) {

    var authFactory = {};

    ...

    authFactory.isPartner = function () {
        if(sessionFactory.get('role') == "partner"){
            return true;
        };
    };

    authFactory.isCustomer = function () {
        if(sessionFactory.get('role') == "customer"){
            return true;        
        };  
    };

    authFactory.isAdmin = function () {
        if(sessionFactory.get('role') == "admin"){
            return true;
        };  
    };

    authFactory.currentRole = function () {
        return sessionFactory.get("role");  
    }

    return authFactory; 

})
.factory('sessionFactory', function () {

    var sessionFactory = {};

    ...

    sessionFactory.get = function (key){
        return localStorage.getItem(key);
    };

    ...

    return sessionFactory; 

});
```

The above is my logic as new in angular, if you have better approach or correction please let me know.

Comment: I think you misunderstand how factories and providers actually work.  That being said, for what you are trying to do, that's what the `resolve` property on your `state` definition is for. https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki#resolve

Comment: @Claies did you mean that I can put role base condition in resolve? would you like to give some example?